# overlap between two patch plots

Tags: matlab

I have two patch plots on the same graph.  One is red and the other blue.  Is it possible to make the overlap purple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the alpha() function, for setting transparency for objects in current axes.  [alpha()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/alpha.html) on the MathWorks online help.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way might be just to alter the [alpha component](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/alpha.html) of one or other patches.